# Проблема с webpack

Tags: webpack, npm

Установил webpack, подключил webpack.config с базовыми настройками, но при вводе команды webpack выбрасывает ошибку - **webpack : The term 'webpack' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- webpack
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (webpack:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**
  ```

Папка dist не создается